# Div и textarea: неодинаковое распределение символов при одинаковых padding

Tags: html, css

То, что Вы видите на рисунке - прозрачная `textarea`, но под ней лежит белый `div`, куда посредством `JavaScript` копируется содержимое из `textarea`. Символы в `textarea` имеют полупрозрачный желтый, в `div` - чёрный, и при точном наложении получается тот цвет, который Вы видите. Хотя оба элемента имеют одинаковые настройки `padding`, как видно, получается не всё совсем одинаково:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```js
$container = $('#container');
$textarea = $('#textarea');
$underlay = $('#underlay');

updateProjection();

$textarea.on('keyup', function(){
 updateProjection();
});

function updateProjection(){

 var textareaContains = $textarea.val();
  textareaContains = '<p>'+textareaContains.replace(/\n\s*\n/g,'</p><p>')+'</p>'; 
  textareaContains = textareaContains.replace(/\n{1}/g,'<br />'); 
 $underlay.html(textareaContains);
  
  var textareaContainsHeight = $textarea[0].scrollHeight;
  
  $textarea.outerHeight(textareaContainsHeight);
  $underlay.outerHeight(textareaContainsHeight);
  $container.height($underlay.outerHeight());

}
```

```css
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body{
  width: 300px;
}

#container{
  background-color: #d6ebf5;
  position: relative;
  padding: 5px 10px;
}

#textarea, #underlay{
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 5px;
    left: 10px;
    padding: 4px 8px;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    width: -webkit-calc(100% - 20px);
    width: calc(100% - 20px);
    height: 70px; // начальная
}

#textarea {
    font-size: 13px;
    outline: none;
    padding: 4px 8px;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 2px;
    resize: none;
    color: rgba(255, 165, 0, 0.5); 
    background-color: transparent;
    z-index: 2;
    caret-color: black;
}

#underlay{
    overflow-x: hidden;
    color: #555555;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    border-radius: 2px;
    z-index: 1;
    line-height: normal;
}

#underlay>p{
  margin: 0;
}

#underlay>p:not(:last-child){
  padding-bottom: 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div id="underlay"></div>
  <textarea id="textarea">Бегом марш! У месторождения кварцующихся фей без слёз хочется электрическую пыль.
  
Съел бы ёж лимонный пьезокварц, где электрическая юла яшму с туфом похищает.ddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddfdfdfdfdfdffdfdfdfdfdfdfd</textarea>
</div>
```

Этот же пример на [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3uqoxf0h/).

Comment: сделайте сниппет повторяющий проблему, не хочется делать это за вас.

Comment: Пордон... Понадобится время, но сделаю.

Comment: небольшая рекомендация для сниппета - чтобы у всех все одинаково было, зафиксируйте ширину body пикселями и пропишите font аттрибуты.

Comment: Сделал всё, как Вы сказали.

Comment: Проверьте `word-break` у параграфа, при `normal` он не захочет рвать слова при переносе.

Comment: А если уберёте `overflow-x: hidden;`, станет заметно, что проблемное слово не переносится.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Длинное слово в блоке не переносится на вторую строку. Если бы блоку не было задано `overflow-x: hidden;`, у него появилась бы горизонтальная прокрутка, и это стало бы заметнее.

Добавьте диву `word-wrap: break-word;`:

> [Свойство word-wrap](https://webref.ru/css/word-wrap) указывает, переносить или нет длинные слова, которые не помещаются по ширине в заданную область.

```js
$container = $('#container');
$textarea = $('#textarea');
$underlay = $('#underlay');

updateProjection();

$textarea.on('keyup', function(){
 updateProjection();
});

function updateProjection(){

 var textareaContains = $textarea.val();
  textareaContains = '<p>'+textareaContains.replace(/\n\s*\n/g,'</p><p>')+'</p>'; 
  textareaContains = textareaContains.replace(/\n{1}/g,'<br />'); 
 $underlay.html(textareaContains);
  
  var textareaContainsHeight = $textarea[0].scrollHeight;
  
  $textarea.outerHeight(textareaContainsHeight);
  $underlay.outerHeight(textareaContainsHeight);
  $container.height($underlay.outerHeight());

}
```

```css
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body{
  width: 300px;
}

#container{
  background-color: #d6ebf5;
  position: relative;
  padding: 5px 10px;
}

#textarea, #underlay{
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 5px;
    left: 10px;
    padding: 4px 8px;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    width: -webkit-calc(100% - 20px);
    width: calc(100% - 20px);
    height: 70px; // начальная
}

#textarea {
    font-size: 13px;
    outline: none;
    padding: 4px 8px;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 2px;
    resize: none;
    color: rgba(255, 165, 0, 0.5); 
    background-color: transparent;
    z-index: 2;
    caret-color: black;
}

#underlay{
    overflow-x: hidden;
    color: #555555;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    border-radius: 2px;
    z-index: 1;
    line-height: normal;
    word-wrap: break-word; /* добавил свойство */
}

#underlay>p{
  margin: 0;
}

#underlay>p:not(:last-child){
  padding-bottom: 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div id="underlay"></div>
  <textarea id="textarea">Бегом марш! У месторождения кварцующихся фей без слёз хочется электрическую пыль.
  
Съел бы ёж лимонный пьезокварц, где электрическая юла яшму с туфом похищает.ddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddfdfdfdfdfdffdfdfdfdfdfdfd</textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: Всё работает, благодарю Вас за ответ! Все бы проблемы так просто решались xD